# The song playing in My Hero Academia season 3 episode 14 at 4:10

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the name of the soundtrack in My Hero Academia season 3, episode 14 beginning at 4:10?

Answer (score 0):

just to make sure was this when the class were being told about special moves?

The next music after that point (beginning 4:25) is 'Kibasen'
Hopefully this is the piece you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's **Kibasen**, the 13th track from disc 1 of *My Hero Academia 2nd Original Soundtrack*.